# Prevent expression evaluation for some values in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I need to plot a function that presents some kind of removable singularity, but I cannot split the plot into two intervals, because I'm setting the domain programmatically and it can happen that the singularity falls out of the domain. I thought of using the `ifthenelse` function, but it's useless because both the expressions in the two branches are evaluated in any case. Look at the following code (it's just an example):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [declare function={%
  y(\x)= \x!=0 ? sin(\x)/\x : 1;}]
\draw plot [domain=0:1] (\x,{y(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I expected that, as x=0, the first branch of the expression was skipped and only the second one was evaluated, but it's not so and I get a division by zero error.
As a solution, I thought of declaring an intermediate function to set properly the independent variable, as in the following working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [declare function={%
  t(\x)= \x!=0 ? \x : 1;
  y(\x)= \x!=0 ? sin(\x)/t(\x) : 1;}]
\draw plot [domain=0:1] (\x,{y(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I'm looking for a more elegant and compact solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same as Kpym's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220923/4686) but with no load of an additional library.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\ifabsgreater #1#2{\ifpdfabsnum 
    \dimexpr#1pt>\dimexpr#2pt\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [declare function={%
          sinc(\x)= \ifabsgreater{\x}{0.001}{sin(\x r)/\x}{1};}]
 \draw[help lines] (-3.5,-1.5) grid (3.5,1.5);
 \draw[red, very thick] plot [domain=-pi:pi, samples=100] (\x,{sinc(5*\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sine cardinal]

Comment: (+1) this is not for javascript programmers like me ;)

Comment: @Kpym  you mean there are no `\expandafter`s in javascript? I am shocked ;)

Comment: I should not have called the thing `\ifabsgreater` but rather, for example `\IfAbsGreater` to signal it does not work as an `\if` conditional requiring a `\fi`.

Comment: I'm trying to modify your function to work with an equal sign but it fails in x=0 like in the question. Is there any way to let it work with the equal sign?

Comment: I am not sure about what you mean. If `\x` is small the TikZ math parsing of `sin(\x r)/\x` will lead to dimension too large error, I imagine. Is this the kind of error you see? you should ask a new question if this too long to explain in a comment.

Comment: No. It isn't a dimension too large error but a division by zero error that is just what I wanted to avoid when I asked to prevent the function from being evaluated in x=0. If I use the @Kpym code substituting the < sign with the = one, it still works good.

Comment: @jfbu, I'm sorry: I mistook the order of the two expressions. Your answer works good too.

Answer (score 11):

Here is one possibility using `math` tikzlibrary:

```
\documentclass[border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{
  function sinc(\x) {
    if  abs(\x) < .001 then {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return sin(\x r)/\x;
    };
  };
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (-3.5,-1.5) grid (3.5,1.5);
  \draw[red, very thick] plot [domain=-pi:pi, samples=100] (\x,{sinc(5*\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]